# Third level of CSS dropdown menu does not work

Tags: css

I have a 2-level CSS dropmenu menu working nicely - taken from the web.

I'm pretty new to CSS and tried to mod it to work with 3-levels but unfortunately I failed...

Screen shot of my 3rd level menu fail:

http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a498/paul1234562/menu-screen_zpsb180cdfa.jpg

Update: note the third-level menu is supposed to display to the right of its parent menu, not over it and the other sub-menus.

You can see the menu here:

http://etfsage.ca/test/

Under 'Canada Equity', I wanted the 'Broad Market' submenu to display the third level menu options when the mouse hovers over 'Broad Market'.

If some CSS Guru could help me get this working I would hugely appreciate it.

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
<meta name="description" content="">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test Menu</title>


</head>
<body>


<!-- Display Main Menu !-->
<nav class="cf">
  <nav class="cf">

    <!-- menu nav -->
    <ul class="topmenu">


      <!-- Home -->
      <li class="topmenu"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>



      <!-- Canada Equity ETF -->
      <li class="topmenu"><a href="/index.php#eqCanBroadMarket">Canada Equity <img src="/etf-images/down-arrow.jpg"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanBroadMarket">Broad Market</a></li>
                  <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanSS"> +++Third level menu option #1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanREITS">+++Third level menu option #2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanMC">+++Third level menu option #3</a></li>  
                  </ul>                  
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanSS">Sector Specific</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanREITS">REITs (Real Estate Investment Trusts)</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanMC">Mid-Cap and/or Small-Cap</a></li>         
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqCanMinVol">Minimum Volatility</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>




      <!-- USA Equity ETF -->
      <li class="topmenu"><a href="/index.php#eqUSABroadMarket">USA Equity <img src="/etf-images/down-arrow.jpg"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqUSABroadMarket">Broad Market</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqNASDAQ">NASDAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqUSASmallCap">Small Cap</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqUSASectorSpecific">Sector Specific</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqUSAMinVol">Minimum Volatility</a></li>
          <li><a href="/index.php#eqUSAHighBeta">High Beta</a></li>
          <li><a href="/etfs-active.php">Actively Managed: USA Equity</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>


    </ul>


</nav>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */




html {
    background: #E6E3D4;
}




body {
    font: 100% Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    line-height: 1.2; /* */
}




/*micro-clearfix by Nicolas Gallagher http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/*/
.cf:before, .cf:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear:both;
}

/* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
.cf {
    zoom:1;
}





/* START top level menu: topmenu - works great */
/* START top level menu: topmenu - works great */
/* START top level menu: topmenu - works great */

ul.topmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    background: #006da6; 
    height: 2em;
    width: 100%;

    font: 100% Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;

}
li.topmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

/* ul.sub-submenu defined - newly added as part of my third level menu mod */
/* ul.submenu defined - works great */
/* ul.topmenu defined - great great */

ul.sub-submenu, ul.submenu, ul.topmenu li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index:3; 
}


ul.topmenu li a:hover, ul.topmenu li:hover > a {
    background: #035c7c;
    height: 1.8em;
    padding-top: .3em;
    position: relative;
    top: -.3em;
    border-radius: .3em .3em 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}


ul.current, a:hover.current, ul.topmenu li:hover a.current {
    background: #AD9B7F;
    background: yellow;
    color: #eee;
    padding-top: .3em;
    border-radius: .3em .3em 0 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -.3em;
    border-bottom: .3em solid #917F63;
    cursor: default;
}

ul.topmenu li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
}


/* END top level menu: topmenu - works great */
/* END top level menu: topmenu - works great */
/* END top level menu: topmenu - works great */




/* START level 2: submenu ... works great */
/* START level 2: submenu ... works great */
/* START level 2: submenu ... works great */


ul.submenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 1.8em;
    width: 100%;

    float: none;
    background: #035c7c;
    background: pink;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.8em;
    left: -9000em;
}
ul.submenu li {
    float: none;
}

ul.submenu li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.submenu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.submenu li a:hover {
    background: #15afcb;
    background: red;    
    height: 1.8em;
    padding-top: .2em;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* END level 2: submenu ... works great */
/* END level 2: submenu ... works great */
/* END level 2: submenu ... works great */




/* START level 3: attempted to add Level 3: called it sub-submenu */
/* START level 3: attempted to add Level 3: called it sub-submenu */
/* START level 3: attempted to add Level 3: called it sub-submenu */

ul.sub-submenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    height: 1.8em;
    width: 100%;

    float: none;
    background: #035c7c;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.8em;
    left: -9000em;
}
ul.sub-submenu li {
    float: none;
}

ul.sub-submenu li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding: .2em 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.sub-submenu li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
ul.sub-submenu li a:hover {
    background: #15afcb;
    background: brown;  
    height: 1.8em;
    padding-top: .2em;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-decoration: none; 
}

/* END level 3: sub-submenu */
/* END level 3: sub-submenu */
/* END level 3: sub-submenu */
```

Comment: As any good developer knows,switching gears is a great leap forward in debugging an issue sometimes,I know this menu is rudimentary but it seems unfriendly from a user standpoint,perhaps consider more standardized design patterns that are familiar to many web surfers. Originality can be nice but this menu seems to have a far way to go to get appreciation on that level,check out different "mega menu" designs,because the fact that you are overlaying a menu on top of menu,maybe this is only for your SO question but,if not,not a good direction

Comment: The opening and closing tags do not seem to match (extra `</ul>` and `</div>` above the `</nav>`). Can you double-check this and update the question?

Comment: look at this menu for contrast http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Comment: @BrianOgden The usability of a non-working menu is always going to be bad. :P I'm pretty sure OP did not intend to put a menu on top of a menu. That's the broken part, which is what OP is asking us about.

Comment: Indeed, but I should have made that clear in my problem description.  The broken third level menu is supposed to display to the right of its parent menu - not over it (as shown in my screen shot).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Zhihao - fixed. Note it did not impact code operation but indeed it was an oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is not possible with pure CSS... See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181254/is-there-a-way-to-reference-an-existing-css-style-from-another-css-style-using-c). You can't reference CSS elements through CSS.

What you can do though is use Javascript and dynamically apply the styling needed. For your scenario, I set `display: none` to your class `sub-submenu` and then added a JS script so that on hover, it would find any uls inside and show them. I also moved your `sub-submenu` into the li.

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kvcN/1/

Comment: Nice aug!  Can I ask a huge favor... Could you mod your demo for the third-level menu to display to the right of its parent menu. I never meant for the third-level to display over existing sub-menus. Nicely crafted solution - great job.

Comment: I have a hackish solution which I don't truly approve of but maybe this can be a starting point? I updated the jsFiddle but the general idea is you need to wrap your sub-submenus and move them relatively based on where the li is. If I have more time later, I might try to fix it so its better. Right now I just manually plug in numbers.

Comment: Super Aug. Thank you SOOOOOOO much.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using jQuery rather than css do the interaction.

You can see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joydesigner/sLe5p/) here.

Here is the code of jQuery.

```
$('.submenu li a:first').hover(function(){
                        $('.sub-submenu').show();
                    },
                    function(){
                        $('.sub-submenu').hide();
                    });
```